# Date Diff Not giving right Hours

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I am having issues with date diff. For example

```
            $nToday = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
            $deliveryDateNoon = $_SESSION['sp_date']." 12:00:00";

            $date1 = new DateTime($nToday);
            $date3 = new DateTime($deliveryDateNoon);
            $diffNoon = $date3->diff($date1);
            $hrs = $diffNoon->format('%h');
```

`$ntoday="2014-10-30 10:01:46"`
`$deliveryDateNoon="10/31/2014 12:00:00"`

The value I get for `$hrs` is... 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is correct. [`date_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) returns a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which is the total number of years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds different between two dates.

For example: 1 day 1 hour, 58 minutes, 14 seconds. When you try to get the `hours` from this you will get `1`, not the total amount of hours like you expect. You need to do date math to convert that interval into just the number of hours difference.

```
$hrs = $diffNoon->format('%h') + ($diffNoon->days * 24);
```

- [**Demo**](https://eval.in/213068)

Comment: The demo is your biggest seller ;)